# Display Column information from database into my dropdown

Tags: c#, html, .net, sql

I am trying to display Column information from database into my dropdown. After selecting the item in the dropdown (1) the next dropdown (2) must show the list of items present in selected field..net

Comment: What a lovely story. I hope you pressed 'submit' early and had alot more to add.

Comment: ok, so what's the problem you are facing ? have you tried something ?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET dropdownlist you can set autopostback to true and in the codebehind set the items in the second droplist.

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOBTmp", Convert.ToInt32(txtDOB.Text));

Comment: is the above code right> its declared as [DOB] [date] in database